# Executing bash script and entering to menu option

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which shows a MENU when is executed.So, the  user can select an option (1,2,3,4,...).

But now I also need to program a crontab that execute the script and automatically selects option 2 in the menu.

Any way to do that? Lice executing the script and doing and echo "2"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few options.  One is [`expect`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) which allows you to expect and respond to the program.  The other is simply piping into the program, for example, `echo "2" | /path/to/your/script.sh`.  Alternately, I would simply recommend that you modify your script to simply accept parameters.